# Sql sub query with addition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to get the id's like in the query i wrote here.

```
SELECT id 
FROM `ActivityLog` 
WHERE `activityAt` >= '2015-01-23 00:00:00' 
AND `module` LIKE 'Api' 
AND `data` LIKE '%"status":false%' 
AND ( `action` LIKE 'DeviceSignUp'  OR  `action` LIKE 'UniversityStudentSignUp')
```

For these id's i want to add 1 and search them all.

for example, if my query returns 10,12,14,16 i want to add 1 to each and search for 11,13,15,17 through in query.

```
SELECT *
 FROM `ActivityLog`
 WHERE id in (11,13,15,17);
```

how is it possible to do the addition part ?

Comment: Is this mysql or sql-server? Please pick one and delete the other tag.

Comment: LIKE without wildcards is the same as =. (Except for trailing blanks...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM ActivityLog WHERE id in 
(
  SELECT id + 1 FROM ActivityLog 
  WHERE activityAt >= '2015-01-23 00:00:00' 
   AND module LIKE 'Api' AND data LIKE '%"status":false%' 
   AND ( action LIKE 'DeviceSignUp' OR  action LIKE 'UniversityStudentSignUp' )
)
```